# Reloading my React hook page causes my browser to trigger <noscript> element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

As the title already explains a lot of the problem,

I just developed a simple application in React Hook, my current routes are defined by

```
   <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/products/:category' element={<ProductBrowsing/>}/>
        <Route path='/productsDetails/:id' element={<ProductDetails/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

testing all these routes in my local machine, it was possible to navigate in all pages either by calling the `<Link>` component or by putting directly through the URL

when I went to the process of deploying my application and putting it inside a VPS, I realized that a call by `<Link>` is passable unless the `/:category` attribute is not the same, which causes the page not to load even if the URL changes (and im passing a lot of parameters that doenst affect the page as a result of this), so the next solution imagined was to always refresh the page to force the component to load with the correct URL, but always when I try to refresh the page in my application I get an immediate response from the  tag returning "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

basically I can no longer navigate my application and im hopeful to know why

Comment: Since this sounds more like a server configuration issue, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to make it work in my case I just had to modify the common answer to this problem which is to go inside the package.json and add

`"homepage": ".",`

all I had to do was change the . to my real domain of the application already in prod